# Difference between two derivative definitions

Tags: limits, derivatives, definition

just been very confused about the definition of these two derivatives the past few days.

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$

and

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

When do i use them? and what are the differences between these two "definitions" and how come they're called definitions and not formulas?

Comment: One is the derivative at $a$; the other is the derivative at $x$

Comment: There’s no difference. Both define the derivative of $f$ **at a point**.

Comment: What is your distinction between a definition and a formula?

Comment: Definition describes something while a formula is like a tool that you use to get the answer

Comment: If that's your distinction, this should come across as both a definition and a formula for you. Look this up on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition)

Answer (score 2):

These formulas are the definition of derivative.

One is the derivative at $a$, $f'(a)$; the other is the derivative at $x$, $f'(x)$.

In essence they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The Right hand derivative of a function **at** $x$ is defined as: 
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
If you had to find the right hand derivative of the function **at** $a$, simply replace $x$ with $a$.

Similarly the left hand derivative is defined as: 
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}$$

Comment: Both your limits are same. The difference between right and left derivatives is controlled by writing $h\to 0^{+}$ and $h\to 0^{-}$. Common Indian textbooks prefer your version without specifying explicitly that $h$ is positive. Thus your answer can be fixed by replacing $h\to 0$ with $h\to 0^{+}$ everywhere.

Comment: A typo in second formula: replace $f(h) $ by $f(x) $ in numerator.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. will fix them